# Expectation of $AA^T$

Tags: expected-value, matrix

Let $A=(bI-Y)\mathcal{I}(Y\geq b)+(aI-Y)\mathcal{I}(Y\leq a)$ where $a$ and $b$ are scalars, $Y$ is a standard normal random variable, and $\mathcal{I}(\cdot)$ is an indicator function. I would like to find $E(AA^T)$.

Comment: What is preventing you from multiplying the matrices and using linearity of expectation?

Comment: @AlexR. I wasn’t sure how the indicator functions would move around.

Comment: multiplying this out will give you combinations of them (they behave as scalars here). Just use the rules of set theory to simplify. For example $I(A)I(B)=I(A\cap B)$ and $I^2(A)=I(A)$

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I was wondering how you would evaluate $E[(bI-y)\mathcal{I}(y\geq b)\mathcal{I}(y\leq a)^T(aI-y)^T]$. Would this just be zero if $b>a$?

Comment: And for $E[(bI-y)\mathcal(y\geq b)\mathcal(y\geq b)^T(bI-y)^T]$, would this just reduce to $(1-\psi(b))\sigma^2$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $y$ and $\psi(\cdot)$ the normal cdf ?

Comment: $I(y\leq a)^T=I(y\leq a)$ since it's a scalar. So they combine to give $I(b\leq y\leq a)$ which means $b>a$ is gives 0.

Comment: For your second comment, $Y$ is presumably a matrix, so you need a multidimensional normal cdf.